# What To Do About MySQL Aborted Connection Errors (Error Reading Communication Packets)

Tags: mysql

I'm using a Delphi application to connect to MySQL. Although my application works correctly, in the MySQL logs, I see a lot of aborted connections with the bracketed error message being either "got an error reading communication packets" or "got timeout reading communication packets."

I'm seeing dozens of these, although the application seems to be functioning correctly. What do these mean, and more importantly, what do I do about them?

**Edit:** This coincided with me enabling error logging on the MySQL server. Hmm....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although they could be a symptom of a larger problem, they can be caused from normal (i.e. unpreventable) network issues.

Even if they're on the same LAN, for a variety of reasons, communication errors may occur between your application server and the database. In the cases of corrupt communications or time-outs, the applications and/or MySQL most likely retries and works and the problem never surfaces or makes itself apparent.

In my experience, the most common sources of these types of messages are from the application (server) flaking out, the application not terminating connections properly, or from latencies in off-site replication.

Quite likely they were happening *before* you enabled error logging on the MySQL server.

Comment: I have two installations of my application. The one in question has several of these errors. The other does not. That pretty much rules out the possibility of it being flaky code, since it's in one version and not the other.

Comment: Do both installations use the same (timeout) configurations? Support the same functionality? Use the same DNS servers?